# Как программно получить путь папке проекта на C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Как получить путь к проекту (не там, где exe'шники, а где исходники?)

Comment: Провел в гугле последние 2 дня, все что нашел - переменные qmake (типа "_PRO_FILE_PWD_", но как юзать - никто не говорил

Comment: Зачем вам эта информация? И чем вы собираете проект?

Comment: ¿Где собираетесь получать этот путь? Если в собранном приложении, то никак, разве что самостоятельно прописать этот путь при сборке в какую-нибудь константу.

Comment: ну может человеку нужно вот такое `const char* current_filename = __FILE__;` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35732901/4711135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не самый красивый способ, но он работает

```
QString pwd = "";
char * pwd_char = getenv ("PWD");
pwd.append(pwd_char);
std::cout << pwd << std::flush;
```

Comment: Это если из IDE запускать проект, а если нет, то тоже работает? )

Comment: если с qmake, то должно работать

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно. Мне нужно именно из IDE.